# How do you put a sim_float4x4 matrix into a metal buffer in metal in swift?

Tags: ios, matrix, metal

Hi I am trying to program an app that will display simple 3d models in iOS on Xcode and I have run into a small problem but I can not find a solution to this problem in Apples Documentation or in any forums on the internet I have looked in. I have an big array with vertices for triangles in 3 Dimensions that I want to transform into world space in the rendering process in metal. I read in an article online that in order to tell metal to tell the graphics processor to transform the vertices in the rendering process you need to put this matrix in a metal buffer and then tell the rendering process to use this buffer with the matrix in it in this line of code:

```
renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(ROTMATRIX, offset: 0, index: 1)
```

if "ROTMATRIX" is the name of the metal buffer that contains the models rotation matrix. The problem is that I do not know how to put the matrix inside this buffer. I constructed a matrix for the model called MODMAT like this:

```
var A = simd_float4(1, 0, 0, 0)
var B = simd_float4(0, 0, 0, 0)
var C = simd_float4(0, 0, 1, 0)
var D = simd_float4(0, 0, 0, 1)

var MODMAT = float4x4([A, B, C, D])
```

I tried to put the matrix MODMAT in ROTMATRIX in this line of code:

```
ROTMATRIX.contents().copyMemory(from: MODMAT, byteCount: 64)
```

But the compiler in Xcode says that it "Cannot convert value of type 'float4x4' (aka 'simd_float4x4') to expected argument type 'UnsafeRawPointer'". So I need to provide it with the unsafe raw pointer to the matrix MODMAT. So is it possible to create this kind of pointer to a Matrix in Swift and if not how should I modify ROTMATRIX in the correct way?

Best Regards Simon

Answer (score 0):

`contents` returns an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`. You can use either `storeBytes(of:toByteOffset:as:)` or `storeBytes(of:as:)` to store a `simd_float4x4` to this pointer. In fact, you can use this to store any value of a trivial (basically, values that can be copied bit for bit without any refcounting and so on) type.

Refer to documentation page for [`UnsafeMutableRawPointer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer) and [`contents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlbuffer/1515716-contents)

Comment: Thank you i can not try this now but i will try it when I am home.

Comment: Did that work for you?